# Specifying in Maven the IntelliJ package prefix for source and test folders

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ you can specify the package prefix (for example, I usually specify com.abc.project1 as root folder for source folder src/main/java, src/main/scala, src/test/java, etc) in ProjectStructure > Modules > Sources.

However these are overwritten if I have set "Import maven projects automatically".

How do I specify a source package prefix in the pom file?

Comment: whats so difficult about keeping your sources in src/main/java/com/abc/project1/ ?

Comment: The sources are in src/main/java/com/abc/project1/.  It's just a convenience feature in Intellij that allows for the package com.abc.project1.package1 to be seen directly under src/main/java in the Intellij Project View as package1 (rather than as com/abc/project1/package1)

Comment: then no, there's no equivalent for maven

Answer (score 0):

The default in Maven is to specify the package within the `src/main/java` folder which means in other words to put the sources into `src/main/java/com/abc/project1`. Apart from that a package name which contains a thing like `project1` sounds not that good.

Comment: the package is com.abc.project1.package1, and it's in the right folder. See my comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to achieve folder structure like this:

- root_folder

  - *pom.xml (agregate pom xml file)*
  - com

    - abc

      - project1

        - *pom.xml (your existing project)*
        - src

          - main

            - java

              - package1

This can be achieved with the addition of [aggregate pom.xml](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/Getting_Started/files/Develop-Aggregator.html) besides your existing pom.xml

- **aggregate pom.xml**: This POM file specifies which sub-projects (= modules) to build.

  - Its  `<modules>` element defines the list of Maven sub-projects to build. In your case you need to specify `<module>com/abc/project1</module>`
  - Furthermore its `<packaging>` element must be set to pom (not jar): `<packaging>pom</packaging>`
  - put this file into  root_folder
- pom.xml for each individual **sub-project (=module)**.

  - in your case pom.xml must have its `<groupId>` element set to package1: `<groupId>package1</groupId>`
  - Put this file into *project1* folder.

In command line move to root_folder and call `$ mvn clean install`
Jar will be created in `root_folder\com\abc\project1\target\`

You can create a new project in IntellJ by importing aggregate pom.xml. It will not owerwrite folder structure(solving your problem).

Aggregate pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>aggregate-artifact-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>Aggregate POM example</name>
  <description>Aggregate POM example</description>


  <modules>
    <module>com/abc/project1</module>
  </modules>


</project>
```

sub-project(=module) pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>package1</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>my-app archetype</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```